# how to check / verify if Google Cloud Messaging is Accessible in your server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

During the development period, i have successfully deployed Google Cloud Messaging in my Desktop ( running local host wamp) and in my android phone.

But what happens was, when i upload it to the production server (which is being managed by someone, a third party perhaps) the page just keeps loading. and after 30 seconds, i received a timeout.

How do i know / test if this link is working on my webserver? Any other things to enable / disable? Its like i need to justify to the Server Admin, why my php page is working on my localhost but not in their server. Any other things to check.

here is the link https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Additional Info :

Key for server applications
IPs : Any IP allowed

Tested in Localhost : {"multicast_id":8668540645934921720,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1432739962159210%1912cce2f9fd7ecd"}]}

CURL is Enable in PHP Server Production

Comment: I would suggest checking the logs from your production server. Depending on your server provider, you may need to add some configuration files. It may also help to check your Developers Console for any GCM-related errors, though I would check your server logs first.

Comment: @Koh, i have checked tha APACHE LOGs, but there were no logs on it, except , the code execution reached its timeout. So a timeout error was found , which i think its normal, Where do i checked the GCM errors in developer console?